# Returning from a function in nested Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, for-loop, task-parallel-library

Here the code Snippet, I want to exit from the function when the condition meets. How can i achieve this?

```
bool MyNestedFunction()
{
   Parallel.Foreach (ListofStrings_A, OuterString =>//loopA
   {

       Parallel.Foreach (ListofStrings_B, InnerString //loopB
       {
          string FirstTemperedString = Temperedstring.Substring(0,Temperedstring.LastIndexOf(" "));
          string LastTemperedString = Temperedstring.Substring(Temperedstring.IndexOf(" "));

          string FirstOuterString = OuterString.Substring(0, OuterString.LastIndexOf(" "));
          string LastOuterString = OuterString.Substring( OuterString.IndexOf(" "));

          if (FirstTemperedString.Equals(FirstOuterString) || LastTemperedString.Equals(LastOuterString))
          {
                return true; // I want to return from the function (MyNestedFunction)here
                // What will be the alternate code here
          }
        });
    })

    return false;
}
```

What will be the alternative statement for return true, that will exit this function?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `Parallel.Foreach` does

Comment: @Sayse perhaps you could hint him to the right direction then? This isn't very constructive.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis - I don't know what direction the OP needs to go in so how can I point them in a direction? - OP, Parallel.Foreach will run the iterations of the foreach loop in a parallel fashion

Comment: @Sayse I just meant that only saying "I think you're misunderstanding" doesn't contribute, and is perhaps just as useful as saying nothing (although you did get two upvotes :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the two loops can be executed on different threads you have to introduce shared state between the controlling thread and the running threads handling the [ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256691%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) calls. In this case a boolean can be [assumed to be atomic updateable and therefor threadsafe so no locking is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433374/is-locking-access-to-a-bool-required-or-is-it-overkill).

In the if condition set the `result` bool to true and then call `state.Stop();` to signal that the outerloop should end. When it does control is returned to the calling thread while `result` is now true and that value is returned to the caller.

```
bool MyNestedFunction()
{
   bool result = false; // shared state!

   Parallel.ForEach (ListofStrings_A, (OuterString, state) =>//loopA
   {

       Parallel.ForEach (ListofStrings_B, InnerString => //loopB
       {
          string FirstTemperedString = Temperedstring.Substring(0,Temperedstring.LastIndexOf(" "));
          string LastTemperedString = Temperedstring.Substring(Temperedstring.IndexOf(" "));

          string FirstOuterString = OuterString.Substring(0, OuterString.LastIndexOf(" "));
          string LastOuterString = OuterString.Substring( OuterString.IndexOf(" "));


          if (FirstTemperedString.Equals(FirstOuterString) || LastTemperedString.Equals(LastOuterString))
          {
                result = true; // set the return value
                state.Stop(); // signal to Stop the ForEach on all Threads
          }
        });
    });

    return result;
}
```